# Eclipse Android plugin not listing attributes with auto-complete for custom component

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin

In general, the Eclipse Android plug in is working as expected with auto-complete.  However, it is not working for a custom control that I wrote.  Basically, the auto complete list is empty other than the default namespace options.

The control inherits from the Button widget and adds some additional text.  I have a couple of extra attributes that I use defined as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources> 
    <declare-styleable name="SubTextButton"
        <attr name="sub_text" format="string" />
        <attr name="sub_text_size" format="float" />
        <attr name="sub_text_color" format="color" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

otherwise it uses all the standard attributes of the Button widget.

In the layout file I specify the namespace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mycompany"
    ...
```

and I use the control:

```
<com.mycompany.SubTextButton
    android:layout_width="@dimen/status_bar_button_w"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/status_bar_button_h"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
    android:text="HCD"
    android:textColor="@color/static_text"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_standard"
    app:sub_text="SET"
    app:sub_text_size="12.0"
/>
```

Everything works fine, but users don't have the benefit of the auto-complete to see what attributes are available.  Ideally, I'd like to see the inherited `Button` attributes as well as the custom attributes I've defined.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not even the normal attributes work when you do a custom view. I really don't know why :(

Comment: I've asked pretty much a same question about two months ago, and I couldn't get any meaningful response. Hopefully, this time will be luckier for us = )

Comment: And you used the "Android xml" file type?

Answer (score 1):

It does not work for me, either, on Eclipse helios with ADT v0.9.7

However, it could be possible (thanks to the `resources` xml file and the introspection of the parent class).
I had a (longer than expected) look in the ADT source code (I love open-source), and I think it should work. The method `computeAttributeProposals(...)` from [`AndroidContentAssist`](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/sdk.git;a=blob;f=eclipse/plugins/com.android.ide.eclipse.adt/src/com/android/ide/eclipse/adt/internal/editors/AndroidContentAssist.java) reads attributes in an `ElementDescriptor` and it seems they should be correctly initialized for custom controls thanks to [`CustomViewDescriptorService`](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/sdk.git;a=blob;f=eclipse/plugins/com.android.ide.eclipse.adt/src/com/android/ide/eclipse/adt/internal/editors/layout/descriptors/CustomViewDescriptorService.java)

Answer (score 0):

I found that closing all the Properties views and reopening caused my custom attributes to be shown